# Quadratic equation in ring $\mathbb{Z}/1105\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quadratics

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Find the solutions of
>
> $x^2 + 2x +2 = 0$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/1105\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know how to solve this. I surely can't check all the possibilities.

---

Ok. I've now split it up. and found:
$(x+1)^2 = 4 \bmod 5, \quad x = 1,2 \bmod 5$
$(x+1)^2 = 12 \bmod 13, \quad x =4,7 \bmod 13$
$(x+1)^2 = 16 \bmod 17, \quad x= 3, 12 \bmod 17$
but I don't know how to get the answer using the CRT

Comment: Do you know the chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: $1105=5\cdot 13\cdot 17$.

Comment: First, complete the square, so you need $(x+1)^2=-1$.

Comment: Yes, you can check them all.  You can just compute this in a spreadsheet.  Using copy down $1105$ lines is not so many, then you can scan them by eye.  It is easier to factor $1105=5\cdot 13 \cdot 17$, solve in each of those moduli, and combine the results using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Ok. I've now split it up. and found
(x+1)^2 = 4 mod 5, x = 1,2 mod5
(x+1)^2 = 12 mod 13, x =4,7 mod 13
(x+1)^2 = 16 mod 17, x= 3, 12 mod 17

but I don't know how to get the answer using the CRT.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** there's a formula for the solutions of a system of *two* linear congruences with coprime moduli $m$ and $n$:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv a \pmod m, \\ x\equiv b \pmod n.\end{cases} $$
Start from a *Bézout's identity* $\; um+vn=1$. The solutions are given by this formula:
$$x \equiv bum+avn\pmod{mn}.$$
So you can first obtain the solutions mod. $5\times 13$, and thence  the solutions mod. $65\cdot 17$. In all you'll have $8$ roots for the quadratic equation.